# Mailbox unsubscribed customer check

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I just sent an email to 200 people and in the tracking/sends I can only see 191 sent.

Is there a way to check why the remaining 9 didn't get my email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best place to find this info without going through SF Support is to grab it from the [NotSentEvent SOAP Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/notsentevent.htm) or the [NotSent Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5) Activity.

These options will contain a list of all the emails that were entered into the send queue but were not sent to. This includes those that were suppressed or excluded via List Detective or similar as well as those that had errors or other similar issues.

If you only need a small amount (like it sounds like you do) and you have API experience, utilizing the SOAP NotSentEvent Object would be your best bet.

[image]

Otherwise by using the Tracking extract you can export, and then either utilize Excel or similar to view the CSV or re-import into SFMC DE and view there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington. I don't have access to the API unfortunately and never used the Tracking extract option. I looked on the web but couldn't find a tutorial. Would you please help me with some steps or a link?

Comment: This is a bit old so some of the stuff may need to be adjusted accordingly, but this is a decent guide for building a Tracking Extract: https://blog.openbridge.com/export-tracking-data-from-salesforce-marketing-cloud-8a0a4c1f37dc

Answer (score 3):

You can request SFMC Support to provide you this. Assuming all Contacts were opted-in or were not existing in AllSubscribers List, the most probable reason is then the [**List Detective**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335444&type=1&mode=1).

Marketing Cloud filters out, by default, some standard Emails such as `info@brandname.com`, `admin@brandname.com` and such. This list of 'banned' prefixes and known spam-trap domains is quite huge, covers all the language variations and is not provided to any client.

In case you want to send to those 'banned' prefixes, you will need to request manual enablement for sending to those via support.